# Coding standard validator for angular

Tags: angular, sonarqube

Is there any module (way) to validate and define the rules for the angular application  coding standard with report generation (Currently using cli getting the code coverage report)?

Also is possible to validate in sonar, as of now i can validate the template files for the w3c standard.